# Regular Expressions with regularexpressionvalidator

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to create a

```
 <asp:regularexpressionvalidator>
```

with following conditions:

- String must be have 8 chars.
- String must contains 8 alphanumeric chars in any order, letters must be capitals.

Eg:

- YES: 12345678
- YES: A2345A78
- YES: ABCDEFGH
- NO: 1234a567
- NO: ABCdEfgh
- NO: abcdefgh
- NO: a.bc-feg

by the way, anyone knows a good regex online creator? Thanks

RESOLVED: For the first answer view the accepted answer, for the second view the first comment of this post by  Jeff Turner

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910220/any-good-regular-expression-creator-software-or-online-tools-to-create-regular-e

for your regex creator question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the validator, this will work: `[A-Z0-9]{8}`. For a plain Regex match, you would need to specify that that should match the whole string, like `^[A-Z0-9]{8}$`, but the regex validator already has an extra rule that the whole string must be matched instead of just a part.

Explanation:

- `[A-Z0-9]` will match any capital letter (A .. Z) and any digit (0 .. 9)
- `{8}` repeat the previous exactly 8 times